# How can I get the cached leaderboard score, when offline?

Tags: google-play-games

After the initial sign in, it seems that GPGS can keep the user in the "signed in" state, even when offline. So, I can play as if I'm connected, and then, when I have actual connectivity, my scores/achievements are synced.

This is great, but it doesn't seem to work when trying to retrieve a score from the leaderboard, when offline:

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
        gameHelper.getApiClient(), 
        LD_ID, 
        LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
        LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LoadPlayerScoreResult>(){

                @Override
                public void onResult(LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                        LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
                        Player.bestScore = (int)c.getRawScore();
                }

});
```

When online, c.getRawScore() works as expected, but when offline, c is null (to my surprise, because I reasoned that it would just fall back to the cached score, if offline).

Is there any way to get the cached leaderboard score?

Comment: I have not tried this, and wasn't aware that it wouldn't work when offline. If it does behave that way then the best way would be to keep a local copy of the best leaderboard score (when online) and use that value instead when your code returns null. Basically just cache it in your app (and save it to persistent storage).

Answer (score 0):

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(
        gameHelper.getApiClient(), 
        LD_ID, 
        LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
        LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>(){

                @Override
                public void onResult(LoadPlayerScoreResult res) {
                        Status status = res.getStatus();
                        int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

                        if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA) {
                            System.out.println("A network error occurred while attempting to retrieve fresh data, and no data was available locally.");
                        } else if (statusCode == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_STALE_DATA) {
                            System.out.println("A network error occurred while attempting to retrieve fresh data, but some locally cached data was available. The data returned may be stale and/or incomplete.");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(status.getStatusMessage());
                        }
                }

});
```

I havn't tested this code but it should work. It's some debugging code to help with your problem. Run this while online and offline and see what you get in each case.